# AndroidManifest.xml suddenly corrupted?

Tags: android, xml

So I was in the process of adding a `Service` to my app. When I tried to run the app on my phone, the AndroidManifest.xml suddenly "corrupted". I have no idea what's going on or how I can fix it. I've tried Build --> Clean but I get the `@drawable/icon').` error which you can see below. I haven't moved any files or nothing, I just created a `Service` activity and added `<service` `</service>` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`. And every R.fo.bar is displaying `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Error message:**

> C:\Users\ASABANOV\Documents\PowerSupplyTool\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Error:(17, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').
>
> Error:(18, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/service_name').

**debug\AndroidManifest.xml**

[image]

**main\AndroidManifest.xml**

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: is service_name defined in your strings.xml?

Comment: whoops...  forgot about that. Added the icon in drawable aswell. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you know that your service suppose to be placed in application tag right? :)

Comment: @Hellboy oh.. haha, didn't know that. this is my first time using a service.. how should it look?

Comment: just place it in your application tag in manifest just like your activities :)

Comment: You seriously don't know how to add drawables to your app? That's one of the most basic things. Anyhow, you probably don't need the icon and just delete that line, then it just defaults to the <application>'s icon

Comment: Yes, you need to add an image file with the name icon in your drawable folder and then you will not get that error again.

Comment: @Hellboy I updated the OP. The app runs but there's still some highlighted in red?